# Ошибка смены статуса заказа WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На сайте после переноса на другой хостинг появились проблемы. Есть Яндекс.Касса и СДЕК. После оплаты онлайн, касса создает заказ с статусом в обработке. Раньше он улетал в СДЕК, так же отправлялось письмо о новом заказе Администратору - теперь этого нет.

**Что могло повлиять на это?**

Пытался выводить логи, но ничего полезного нет. Хуки на смену статуса не отрабатывают, по крайней мере пробовал ловить смену на в Обработке

логи:

```
2020-12-07T12:42:38+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Class 'XMLWriter' not found in /var/www/sitedir/data/www/site.ru/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/api/legacy/v1/class-wc-api-xml-handler.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/sitedir/data/www/site.ru/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-edostavka/includes/admin/class-wc-edostavka-orders.php(174): WC_API_XML_Handler->generate_response(Array)
#1 /var/www/sitedir/data/www/site.ru/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-edostavka/woocommerce-edostavka.php(75): WC_Edostavka_Orders->generate_delivery_request()
#2 /var/www/sitedir/data/www/site.ru/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): WC_Edostavka->export_order_on_payment(21826)
#3 /var/www/sitedir/data/www/site.ru/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#4 /var/www/sitedir/data/www/site.ru/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#5 /var/www/sitedir/data/www/site.ru/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php(350): do_action('woocommerce_ord...', 218 в /var/www/sitedir/data/www/site.ru/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/api/legacy/v1/class-wc-api-xml-handler.php на строке 69
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На хостинге отсутствует расширение php xmlwriter

Для Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Для CentOS

```
yum install libxml2

yum install php-xmlwriter

yum install php-xml
```

Либо если есть панель на хостинге - установите расширение через панель